# Jquery : Cannot add content with before() on a cloned block of code using prototype

Tags: jquery

I've some blocs of code that need to be cloned every time I clic a button, I'll explain:
there is a button nammed *NEW BL*, when clicked it must add a new bloc (BL),
inside the bl block there is another button that when clicked adds new *ARTICLE* inside this BL bloc,

so that many BL can be created, and could have some article inside them,

**The problem** : in the first BL I can create articles, the button create article in the first bl is working taking into account that the first BL is generated on the page loading. HOWEVER when I click on a button inside the second or the third bl (dynamically created) in order to add a new article, nothing is added.

Any idea plez,
thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was with the exact values of the ids that I passed to add content after, and to perform events with dynamically generated content, I used live() for this purpose.
tnx